# CSS code structure decision

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, design-decisions

I'm currently working on an header for some website. This header consists of two different designs:

**Floating/horizontal header:**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      +--------------+                       +--------------------+      |
|      |     LOGO     |                       | Menu | Menu | Menu |      |
|      +--------------+                       +--------------------+      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Centered header:**

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                          +--------------------+                         |
|                          |        LOGO        |                         | 
|                          | Menu | Menu | Menu |                         |            
|                          +--------------------+                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The *centered header* should be used, when the browser width is smaller than some breakpoint value. Otherwise the horizontal header. This can be achieved via CSS `media-queries`. My question is what the better code organisation would be for the *header.css* file:

1. Only use code intersection of the two designs (`font-family`, `container-width: 100%`, etc.) together with two media queries.

**Pseudo code:**

```
/* Code necessary for both designs */

@media-query (width < breakpoint) {
  /* upgrade code to centered header */
}

@media-query (width >= breakpoint) {
 /* upgrade code to floating header */
}
```

2. Always use centered header + `media-query` to override necessary pieces:

**Pseudo code:**

```
/* Code necessary for centered designs */

@media-query (width >= breakpoint) {
 /* Overwrite centered header code */
 /* Insert floating header code */
}
```

My question is what are the **pros**/**cons** of these two css structures? How about code duplication. The first one *always* uses a `media-query` to display anything useful. The second one needs to overwrite some of the first centered headers features.

I hope this doesn't get closed, because it's too subjective. I'm only asking for **pros**/**cons**, *not* what design to chose or which one is *better*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely not suggest your first example, based on readability and just general CSS principles. The idea of using both a `greater than` AND a `less than` is redundant and somewhat confusing - it's the equivalent of doing two if statements for one condition.

Order your media queries in either descending or ascending order, leaving your default styles as either the screen at its largest, or at its smallest.

Personally I define all the full-width styles outside of any media query, and then use `max-width` as I traverse down the stylesheet, defining smaller and smaller screen sizes. That being said, the opposite is also completely acceptable and common, where you define your mobile sizes outside of any media queries, and traverse downwards *increasing* in size (using `min-width`). Both methods create an easy-to-follow example - if I were to work on this file after you, I would know exactly where to find the change I'm looking for.

I'd say one thing that should be agreed upon though is that using *both* `min-width` and `max-width` in your `@media` queries is never a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm actually thinking about writing the header with [SASS](http://sass-lang.com). In SASS I'm able to use function-like functionality to use something like `upgrade_to_centered()`/`upgrade_to_floating` in two `media-queries` (this is cleaner I think). The final CSS would look like the first example above. Would you still go with the second approach? I just think, that it would be a bit painful to first of all reset the *default* design before setting the new one in a `media-query`. This does not occur with two media-queries..

Comment: Two media queries is just extra work and generally redundant. If you do `#myDiv { color: red; }   @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { #myDiv { color: blue; } } `, it is the exact same thing as doing `@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) { #myDiv { color: red; } } @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) { #myDiv { color: blue; } } ` It's extra unnecessary markup and is *less* readable, which is the opposite of what you want in your external file includes.

Comment: You are right. I only had something in mind like `#myDiv { display: inline-block; font-size: 10px; } @media (max-width: 500px) { #myDiv { display: block; font-size: 12px; } }` vs. `@media (min-width: 501px) {  #myDiv { display: inline-block; font-size: 10px; } } @media (max-width: 500px) { #myDiv {font-size: 12px; } }` (one line less, but this adds up..).

Comment: Yes, it's the equivalent of doing `if (myVariable > 500) { do this }  if (myVariable <= 499) { do this }` - It works, it's just unnecessary.

Comment: My example uses one line less. Since it doesn't need to reset the `display` to `block`. Did you notice that? This will add up with more advanced code I think, but I will still use your approach, since - as you already mentioned - it's the more separated way.

Comment: In your example, just remove the second media query and put that rule beforehand, like so: `#myDiv {
   font-size: 12px; 
} 

@media (min-width: 501px) { 
   #myDiv { 
     display: inline-block; 
     font-size: 10px; 
   } 
} ` - Like I said, in some cases you may want to define the smallest size and use media queries to move UP in size if you find it more appropriate.